# How to find 95% credible interval of a posterior predictive distribution?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, markov-chain-montecarlo, credible-interval

I obtained a posterior predictive with 1,000 samples using MCMC, and I need to quantify the 95% credible intervals.
I know that the difference between confidence intervals and credible intervals. One is on the frequentist; the other is in a probabilistic sense.
The issue is how to quantify the 95% credible intervals of a sampled and discrete distribution since the analytical expression of CDFs and PDFs remains unknown.

Here I attached a figure of the sampled posterior distribution.
The mean and std are 9.4336e+4 and 1.1112e+04.

Please help me with how to calculate the credible intervals with the above information of the targeted distribution.
I appreciate your help and advice! [image]

Comment: Since your posterior is unimodal, can you not just use the eCDF/quantiles to estimate it? If there are no analytical solutions, then, with "enough" samples from the posterior, where 95 % of the samples fall is where 95 % of the probability density is.  Assuming your posterior is an unbiased estimator of your parameter, then there is a 95 % chance the true value is in that region.

Comment: To echo @Baraliuh, the 95% credible interval is derived from the quantiles of the posterior samples. If you'd like alternative kinds of credible intervals (e.g., the 95% highest probability interval), then it is a little harder to get that estimate but is still ultimately based on the posterior samples you've saved. Depending on your model and your MCMC estimator, 1000 posterior samples may be inadequate to fully characterize your parameter of interest